# Use k-means test results for training set SPSS

Tags: spss

I am student working with SPSS (statistics) for the first time. I used 1,000 rows of test data to run k-means cluster tool and obtained the results. I now want to take those results and run against a test set (another 1,000) to see how my model did.

I am not sure how to do this; any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clustering model (or any unsupervised model), there really is no right or wrong result. As such, there is no target variable that you can compare the cluster model result (the cluster allocation) to and the idea of splitting the data set into a training and a testing partition does not apply to these types of models.

The best you can do is to review the output of the model and explore the cluster allocations and determine whether these appear to be useful for the intended purpose.